# import auto invoking function binding this to window object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jestjs

Inside a jest test, I need to import a javascript module that declare some global functions. This javascript module is autogenerated from django (ex jsi18n) and it's an auto invoking function

```
(function(globals) {
    var django = globals.django || (globals.django = {});
    ...
}(this));
```

This is helpful for use the translation inside the react component. For example including a translation string in our `.jsx` file using a global defined function `gettext()`

```
<p>{ gettext('got it') }</p>
```

I've tried to import the module using the standard form

```
import './djangojs';
```

but jest report the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'django' of undefined
```

because `this` it's undefined (strict mode). So I've tried to manual edit the module and adding at the end `}(this || window));` and works correctly. 
But the module is autogenerated every time. So how I can bind `this` to `window` for using the global object without manually editing the file?

Comment: File a bug with whoever maintains Django. Their code generator is nasty. Why don't they use UMD?

Comment: You can just mock entire `./djangojs`.

Comment: How can I mock it? @dfsq

Comment: Use `jest.mock`.

Comment: @dfsq it doesn't work because `this` is still not defined

Comment: `this` is not relevant to mock file. With mock you are not concerned with what real `djangojs.js` does. You only define your own version of `gettext` on global object which will be used be jest.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I have imported the django javascript modules directly using the [setupFiles](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array) as @dfsq told

```
"setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/path/to/jsi18n/djangojs.js",
    "<rootDir>/path/to/js/reverse.js"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is specific to Babel. Babel is commonly used in Jest testing rig, and it is likely used here.

Babel [`transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/) enables strict mode  for both ES module imports and `require`, so `this` is `undefined` in imported module.

In order to make a piece of code executed in loose mode while its context is in strict mode, it should be evaluated in global context:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const script = fs.readFileSync(require.resolve('./djangojs')).toString();
new Function(script)(); // or (0, eval)(script);
```

instead of `import './djangojs'` or `require('./djangojs')`.

It's expected that `script` doesn't have to be transpiled (it will be evaluated as is) and doesn't rely on the context (doesn't use `require`, because it's not available in global context). I.e. `eval` will work for regular script like `./djangojs` but not for CommonJS module.

This may be useful if a module shouldn't be available globally or may vary between tests.

If it should be available for all tests then `setupFiles` should be used, as another answer suggests.